# How to execute a procedure in a select or for every row of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to analyze team schedules in the NBA, and I need to run a procedure on every row in a either a this query ...

```
SELECT
    t.teamname AS team,
    opp.teamname AS opponent, 
    cat.cityname AS at,
    COUNT( * ) AS GamesInCity,
    ( COUNT( * )/ @daysinseason ) AS Pct
FROM schedules s
    INNER JOIN teams t   ON s.teamid     = t.teamid
    INNER JOIN teams opp ON s.oppteamid  = opp.teamid
    INNER JOIN teams at  ON s.hometeamid = at.teamid
    INNER JOIN city c    ON t.cityid     = c.cityid
    INNER JOIN city copp ON opp.cityid   = copp.cityid
    INNER JOIN city cat  ON at.cityid    = cat.cityid
WHERE
    t.teamname = @team
GROUP BY
    cat.cityname
```

or output the query as a tmp table that would ultimately look like this:

[image]

I understand cursors are not ideal, so what's the best way to go about this, or how could I do this? Something like this?

```
SELECT
    t.teamname AS team,
    opp.teamname AS opponent, 
    cat.cityname AS at,
    COUNT( * ) AS GamesInCity,
    ( COUNT( * )/ @daysinseason ) AS Pct, 
    --
    CALL name_of_proc(IN @var, IN (COUNT( * )/ @daysinseason), OUT @out)
    --
FROM
    schedules s
    INNER JOIN teams t   ON s.teamid     = t.teamid
    INNER JOIN teams opp ON s.oppteamid  = opp.teamid
    INNER JOIN teams at  ON s.hometeamid = at.teamid
    INNER JOIN city c    ON t.cityid     = c.cityid
    INNER JOIN city copp ON opp.cityid   = copp.cityid
    INNER JOIN city cat  ON at.cityid    = cat.cityid
WHERE
    t.teamname = @team
GROUP BY
    cat.cityname
```

Note: I have to use the column pct in my called procedure.

Thanks.

UPDATE: The procedure is:

```
SET @team = 'Atlanta Hawks';
SET @daysinseason = 199;
SET @salary = 10000000;
SET @country = 'US';
SET @state = 'NY';
SET @filer= 'SINGLE';

CALL calc_state_tax(@salary, @state, @filer, @staxesDue);

CREATE PROCEDURE `calc_state_tax`(IN `pSalary` DECIMAL(12,2), IN `pStateCode` VARCHAR(2), IN `pFiler` VARCHAR(6), OUT `taxesDue` DECIMAL(9,2)
    )
        LANGUAGE SQL
        NOT DETERMINISTIC
        CONTAINS SQL
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
        COMMENT ''
    BEGIN
    DECLARE taxRate DECIMAL(9,4);
    DECLARE taxExempt DECIMAL(7,2);
    DECLARE deduction DECIMAL(7,2);

    SELECT
        s1.taxrate,
        s1.exemption,
        s1.stddeduction
        INTO taxRate, taxExempt, deduction
    FROM statetax s1
    WHERE s1.statecode = pStateCode  
        AND s1.filer = pFiler 
        AND s1.bracket = (
        SELECT MAX( s2.bracket) 
        FROM statetax s2
        WHERE s1.statecode = s2.statecode
        AND s1.filer = s2.filer
        AND s2.bracket < pSalary);

    SET taxesDue = (((pSalary - deduction) * taxRate));

    END
```

Comment: What does the stored procedure do? If it does not modify the database consider replacing it with a UDF and then using `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: @dai, It doesn't modify the database, just Selects from it. I''l look into a cross apply.

Comment: If it's a scalar function then you don't need to use `CROSS APPLY`, you can use it inline as though it were a built-in function. Only use sprocs if you absolutely have to, most sprocs can be converted to UDFs.

Comment: What would be a scalar function, something that returns one value? If so that is the case.

Comment: A scalar function is a UDF that returns a single value (e.g. an `int` or `float` or `nvarchar(50)`)  value instead of a table.

Comment: Can you provide the query that you need to run per row, and the query that returns all rows you want to query from.

Comment: @CurseStacker, updated. The query that returns all rows you want to query from is the first query without the "call procedure comment"

Comment: change it to a function you can't use a procedure in a select, make it a function (UDF) and it will work

Comment: @Mr. would it be a deterministic or not deterministic?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? in MS-SQL you don't need to specifiy it but I believe it can be deterministic as your function doesn't involve getdate or any non-deterministic sql function

Comment: @Mr. I'm using mysql, I set it as deterministic

Comment: I'm getting an error "You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable".  Maybe I have to use a procedure?

Comment: either apply the log_bin_trust_function_creators=1 or change it to a procedure, I think is just a MySQL security restriction

Comment: take a look at this thread, probably you need to specifiy that you are just reading data.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-logging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute a procedure in a select, there is no way.

A workaround would be to take your results into a temp table or a table variable, loop it with a cursor and execute the procedure for each row and attach the result to your table with an update, what I think is unnecessary

You can accomplish what you want if you change your procedure to a [UDF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191007.aspx), a function can be used inline in your query as you expected the procedure to be

```
SELECT
    t.teamname AS team,
    opp.teamname AS opponent, 
    cat.cityname AS at,
    COUNT( * ) AS GamesInCity,
    ( COUNT( * )/ @daysinseason ) AS Pct, 
    dbo.MyUDF(@var,(COUNT( * )/ @daysinseason)) -- the udf should return what you have as output parameter in your procedure
FROM ...
```

Comment: The hosting I am using doesn't allow super privilege or schema modifications, so I'll have to use a cursor procedures. Thanks though

Comment: did you tried to use RETURNS DECIMAL(9,2(
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA ?

Comment: Yes, I did.  The problem was because I was developing it on a remote server because I was developing on different computers.  When I got home, I dumped a copy of my remote work into my local workbench and local host, and I could create a function no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a cursor. You can not execute a procedure in a select statement for each row of results.

Select statements are all or nothing so you have to fill a cursor, or a temp table first with the result set, then loop each row individually.  No way around it, it's what cursors were made for.  There is nothing wrong with them.